# How to force WKWebView to show mobile version on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, webkit, wkwebview

For some reason we cannot force mobile site presentation in WKWebView on iPad. We tried different things like installing different customUserAgent on webView, or using
Code Block

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction preferences:(WKWebpagePreferences *)preferences decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy, WKWebpagePreferences *))decisionHandler  API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0)){
    preferences.preferredContentMode = WKContentModeMobile;
    if (@available(iOS 14.0, *)) {
        preferences.allowsContentJavaScript = YES;
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow, preferences);
}
```

Nothing seems help and the site shows as desktop which hides all kinds on buttons on the bottom of the page. Safari displays the site perfectly as a mobile version and resizes it properly. What can I do else in order to show the site as mobile?